# Openlayers setStyle method applied to a feature doesn't visually change the style?

Tags: reactjs, openlayers

[I'm using the select interaction with OpenLayers:](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Select-Select.html#getFeatures)

My goal is to simply change the UI display on the map through the feature rather than a layer. Here is what I'm attempting now:

```
selectClick.getFeatures()
selectClick.getFeatures().item(0)
selectClick.getFeatures().item(0).setStyle(
                new Style({
                    stroke: new Stroke({
                        color: '#7e0101',
                    }),
                    fill: new Fill({
                        color: 'rgba(36, 37, 42, .25)',
                    }),
                }),
            );
```

By logging `selectClick.getFeatures().item(0).getStyle()` before and after the change I'm able to see that the style for the feature has been modified. However this doesn't result in a visual update. Any suggestions? Do I have to make the change on the layer instead?

Comment: The recommended way is to specify the selected style in the `style` option for the interaction.  The original style is reset when the feature is deselected (any changes you made would also be lost).

Comment: I need to be able to change the selected feature after a specific interaction and maintain the original selection. Is this even possible? If so, should the change be addressed at the map level and drill down into the layers? Basically, grabbing the collection of layers with map.getLayers() then selecting the proper layer within the collection and updating the style with setStyle? 

As it appears in the documentation, setStyle is only available on render/canvas, features, and layers.  It's not obvious if there is another means to change style dynamically?

Comment: Do you need the Select interaction? You could base the selction on https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/select-hover-features.html but replace pointermove with click and do not reset the previous selection https://codesandbox.io/s/select-hover-features-forked-pq8mz  If you do need the Select interaction set a property on the features when they are selected, and use a style function to determine which style to use based on that https://codesandbox.io/s/select-features-forked-3yq1p

Comment: Alright, I was able to resolve this issue of mine thanks to your tip about setting a style function @Mike. What I ended up doing was applying a style function to the select interaction. That way whenever it's instantiated I have a global control over the appearance based on a key. So, whenever the aforementioned user input is updated I'm able to simply access the selectinteraction item of interest and apply the key with set method. ~End game: 

selectInteraction.getFeatures().item(0).set('customKey', true); 

Thanks again Mike you're the ChuiMonster of OL!